# Action Bar Style Generator Issues

Tags: android, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I am using appcompat and I have tried using the Action Bar Style Generator.  I set my colours etc and then downloaded my zip.  However, once I unzip, the drawables are duplicated so for example:

test.9.png
test 2.9.png
test 3.9.png
test 4.9.png

So I have a total of 4 of the same drawable.  Anyway, I copy my style xml into the values folder and all the png and drawable xml into the drawable folder.  I then edit my manifest accordingly to set the theme.

However, when I run my app, the theme doesn't seem to have taken affect.  Well it actually appears to have a default theme of the blue tab indicator, the white tab text and dark tabs.

Does anyone have any advice on this as I have tried it numerous times and I'm not sure what to do...

code from my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Vdstyle">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

code from the generated styles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- File created by the Android Action Bar Style Generator

     Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
     Copyright (C) 2012 readyState Software Ltd

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Vdstyle</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Vdstyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Vdstyle</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Vdstyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Vdstyle</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Vdstyle</item>


    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Vdstyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Vdstyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu"> 
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_vdstyle</item>   
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_vdstyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_vdstyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_vdstyle</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_vdstyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_vdstyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Vdstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_vdstyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Vdstyle.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Vdstyle</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Vdstyle</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The heirarchy is

res
  --> drawable (containing all assets from generator)
  --> values (containing style xml generated by web app)

both are on the same level.

example of duplication
[image]

below is my tabs with the styles in place
[image]
I hope this improves my question

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some code? Specifically a sample of the styles.xml, drawable.xml and AndroidManifest? If you could also include a screenshot and what the hierarchy for your res/ folder looks like it would be helpful

Comment: hi, I have just updated my question to reflect your request...thanks for your help!

Comment: hi, I have realised that each duplication has different properties, I'm imagining for mdpi, hdpi etc.  Could anyone tell me which relates to which, anyone who might have used this before?

Comment: so does anyone have any experience using this?  The utility I used to extract the files caused an issue as they weren't put into the correct folders, so the duplication issue is sorted, however the theme still isn't taking affect

Comment: Which version of AppCompat are you using? I know that the actionbar style generator isn't compatible with version 21 and on.